# primes and the sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got the following problem.

> Prove that $p=a^4+4b^4 \;\;\;$can not be a prime number, $\;\; p\gt 5$

I know that $p=(a^2)^2+(2b^2)^2$ can be written as the sum of two squares if and only if $\;\;p\equiv 1 \mod \;4$.
Hence $a \equiv 1$ or $a\equiv 3 \mod \;4$ 
I dont know how can I continue from here

Comment: Why can't $1^4+4\cdot1^4$ be a prime number?

Comment: Maybe it should be $p>5$.

Answer (score 3):

$$a^4 + 4 b^4 =  \left( {a}^{2}-2\,ab+2\,{b}^{2} \right)  \left( {a}^{2}+2\,ab+2\,{b}^
{2} \right) 
$$
so, with one notable exception, this can't be prime.

Comment: This is a famous identity called Sophie Germain's Identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain#Honors_in_number_theory

Answer (score 1):

Start from the following 
$$
   p = a^4+4b^4 = (a^2+2b^2)^2-4a^2b^2 = (a^2+2ab+2b^2)
(a^2-2ab+2b^2).
$$
So $p$ can be prime only if 
$$
a^2-2ab+2b^2=1.
$$
Which corresponds to $a=b=1$ and $p=5$.